# Resharper support for Roslyn diagnostics and code fixes in quick actions

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, roslyn

I've written several Roslyn analyzers and code fixes for my solution. I also use R#. Per se, the diagnostics and fixes work fine, also the syntax highlighting indicating the problematic part. However, in R#'s quick actions (Alt+Enter) the fix doesn't show. I have to hover over the warning to show the Roslyn diagnostics and fixes:

[image: Roslyn diagnostics]

but it doesn't appear in R#'s quick actions:

[image: R#'s quick actions]

Is it possible to include those diagnostics and fixes in R#'s quick actions?

I'm using the latest R# version (2019.3.1) and Visual Studio 16.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to enable option "Extensions->ReSharper->Options->Enivronment->Visual Studio features -> Merge Visual Studio light bulb actions into ReSharper action indicator"